# Xamarin how to get output of binding library

Tags: xamarin, binding, xamarin.ios

Hi I'm using native swift libraries in my Xamarin project which have some debug output in them.
The issue is I can't see this output during runtime of my app, after stopping the debugger it's visible in the application output.

Is there a way to get this output during runtime? I'm using VS 2019 for Mac.

Comment: You could post the issue to github https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues .

Comment: I will do but I wasnt exactly sure if it is an actual issue or some option that I'm missing/wrongly configured.